# Grant View Definition for All Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

What is the approach to granting a user the ability to view **all** stored procedures across all schemas?

---

The command such as

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON [dbo].[{SprocNameHere}] TO [{UserNameHere}]
```

is a one trick pony and has to be done in for all sprocs. Is there a more generic way to include all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can grant at a schema scope

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::DBO TO SOMEUSER
```

or the whole database

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO SOMEUSER
```

Comment: I ended up using the *all* method, but knowing that a per schema option is quite valuable. I actually use differing schemas instead defaulting to `dbo`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Is it OK if the other object types also are included? I.e., see that a table exists, see source code for views etc. If so you can do

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO username
```

I.e., exclude the object name, which now default to the current database. Or, if you want to be more explicit:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON DATABASE::database_name TO username
```

I don't think you can include an object type for above. The other solution I can come up with is a scheduled job that loops the procedures and do an explicit GRANT for each object.